# wpf - creating a custom event trigger

Tags: wpf, triggers, datatrigger, eventtrigger

Currently I am using a button trigger on IsChecked, like so:

```
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                ...
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Is there a way to change the `Property="IsChecked"` above to be dependant on a member in my method? such as on a `bool IsCheckedFlag;` ?

So that the trigger gets fired when i change that flag in my code-behind.

Many thanks in advance

Andy

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataTriggers` for this

```
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCheckedFlag}" Value="True">
            ...
        </DataTrigger >
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>


    public bool IsCheckedFlag
    {
        get { return _isCheckedFlag; }
        set { _isCheckedFlag= value; NotifyPropertyChanged("IsCheckedFlag"); }
    }
```